# I know future WeekOfDay and Hour. How can i get DateTime object in .Net?

Tags: .net, datetime

I have timezoneid, DayOfWeek(Sunday. Monday..), and Hour(int) from user input.

How do I get nearest future DateTime object in .net?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `DayOfWeek`? Do you know how far in the future it is? DateTime itself allows parameters in it's constructor, such as year, month, day. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: Yes, DayOfWeek. With just weekday(ex. sunday) and hour, how do I get nearest future datetime object from current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is not tested, but youll get the idea:

```
DayOfWeek _userDOW = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
int _userHOUR = 7;
DateTime _dt = new DateTime.Now;
while (_dt.DayOfWeek != _userDOW) {
    _dt = _dt.AddDays(1);
}

// remove hours, mins and secs
_dt = new DateTime(_dt.Year, _dt.Minute, _dt.Second);

// add user hour
_dt = _dt.AddHours(_userHOUR);
```

Comment: I somehow missed the hour component (That'll teach me to answer Qs before coffee). Rather than duplicate your answer, I've deleted mine and +1'd yours

Comment: On the brigth side, we both missed the TimeZone :P

Comment: Thanks Nick, @Basic. I got the idea. Tested your code, works except that if user input hour is less than current hour, nearest future is a week later.